# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed issue

Tags: database, foreign-keys, mariadb

Please help to understand "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" issue in this code

create TABLE books
(

```
book_id              INT          NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
book_name            VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
book_description     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
book_number_of_pages INT          NOT NULL,
book_state           VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
author_name          VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (book_id)
```

);

create TABLE authors
(

```
author_id      INT          NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
author_name    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
author_surname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
book_name      VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (author_id),
FOREIGN KEY (book_name) REFERENCES books (book_name)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

);

Comment: you need to have `book_id` in `authors` table, and use it define the foreign key as `FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES books (book_id)`

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd create table statement failed, since the referenced column `book_name` in table `books` has no index.

```
create TABLE books (
book_id              INT          NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
book_name            VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
book_description     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
book_number_of_pages INT          NOT NULL,
book_state           VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
author_name          VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (book_id), 
KEY(book_name)
);
```

However it's not a good design to store information (book_name) redundant. Instead of book_name you should store the id.